# delete all duplicate row on mysql and keep one with Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

how to delete all duplicate row on mysql and keep one with Query?

table name is: **transaction**

my duplicate row:

```
reference    type  
---------  --------
        1         9
        1         10
        1         10
        1         10
        1         11
        1         11
```

**correct row:**

```
reference    type  
---------  --------
        1         9
        1         10
        1         11
```

Comment: we dont have row id , i seprate with field type.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `transaction`   
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`col_1`, `col_2`);
```

`ALTER` : is used to modify tables.

`IGNORE`: if the `IGNORE` is in use, only the first row of the duplicated rows is used. So the rest of rows are deleted.

`ADD UNIQUE INDEX`: In order to prevent duplicates, we add `unique indexes` in the current column separately. `Unique indexes` work in a same way like `primary keys`. Although you can have only one `primary key`, `unique indexes` you can have as many as your number of columns, in that way you can raise your safe about the uniqueness of the current column without duplicates.

Comment: please add some description with your answer

Comment: Muhammad Omer: it creates a unique index on the column, basically eliminating duplicates. It would call an error but the ignore overrides that. its basically saving one entry and ignoring/removing the rest by making it unique.

Dirty but very effective!!